# How to implement In-App Purchases in Samsung TV App (Tizen App)

Tags: in-app-purchase, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, samsung

I have made a Samsung TV App with Tizen. The application is good to go. Now I want to add InAppPurchases in my app. For now, I want a one time fee for this app. On other platforms, like Apple TV and Roku TV, we can add payToInstall and the transaction would be made when user installs the app.
In Samsung TV, we can't do that in that way. We have to make products first in the Samsung DPI Portal. Then we have to implement In-App-Purchase flow in the App. I've found the sample of In-App-Purchases [here](https://github.com/SamsungDForum/SamsungCheckout)

I've cloned the repo and loads the project into the tizen studio. I've loaded the SubscriptionSampleApp/CheckoutMovie into the tizen studio. Now I want to test the subscription flow in order to properly understand.
I am testing like this.
By right clicking on my project, select Run As,
Run As > Run configurations.
On clicking Run configurations, dialog box appears to add configurations. So, I've add configuration of Tizen Web Simulator Application (Samsung TV). When I clicked on run, the error appears and the application does not start.
Here are the screenshots attached.
[image]
[image]
[image]

The config.xml file is same, as contained in the repo. All the code is same too!
If you can look into this matter and provide me with a solution or can refer to some docs to find my solution that would be very helpful. And can I test the payment flow in web simulator too?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Aleem Aheer,

```
It seems there is no platform from your screenshot.
```

Plz follow the guide in below link:

1. Guide for loading webapp in Tizen Studio: https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/creating-tv-applications/importing-tv-applications.html
2. Guide for launching webapp in Tizen Web TV Simulator: https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/getting-started/using-sdk/tv-simulator.html

If any problem, plz contact us here, we will check it in time.
Thank you.